# Is there a way to create a horizontal sub nav without position absolute?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal nav with a horizontal sub nav. I'm trying to get the sub nav to wrap and drop to a new line while pushing content below it down. I'm having trouble with this as the sub nav is absolute.

Is there a way to create the horizontal nav without positioning it absolute?

Here is a fiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/eqqqmra7/

CSS

```
ul {
    text-align: justify;
}
ul:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li ul {
    position: absolute; /* Trying to take this out so it pushes content down */
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p>Haiiiii, I should push down if the nav wraps.</p>
```

The example and code are very slimmed down versions of the full nav.

Comment: Have you tried putting position: relative on the ul li? This will make each sub-nav be position relative to it's parent as opposed to being relative to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the subnav's position to inherit from the parent.

The result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/eqqqmra7/1/

Is this what you were looking for?

**CSS**

```
ul {
    text-align: justify;
}
ul:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li ul {
    position: inherit;
}
```